# Homepage trigger not being triggered on new doc (Google workspace add on)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

We've built a Google workspace add on meant for Docs. We've set it up to have a homepageTrigger in the manifest but we're running into an issue where the trigger isn't fired until the doc/page is refreshed. Looking at the executions in our Apps Script project, we're not seeing any runs of our homepage function at all.

It remains stuck on this loading screen when pressing the add on icon the first time. After refreshing and pressing the add on icon, the homepageTrigger gets fired and the add on loads correctly.

This happens on both a test deployment and when installed via the G Suite store. Using Chrome

Any idea what could be happening?

Repro steps (you can [get the add on here](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/fable/186707740353))

1. Open up a new Google Doc
2. Tap the Fable add on icon in the right sidebar
3. Notice that its stuck on the loading screen
4. Refresh the page
5. Tap the Fable add on icon in the right sidebar
6. Notice that it loads correctly now

This is what the manifest looks like (the 'onHomepage' function is not even being triggered the first time I tap the add on icon. It only gets triggered after refreshing the page/doc and hitting the icon again)

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "FirestoreApp",
        "version": "33",
        "libraryId": "1VUSl4b1r1eoNcRWotZM3e87ygkxvXltOgyDZhixqncz9lQ3MjfT1iKFw"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://fable-mvp.web.app/",
    "https://auth.atlassian.com/",
    "https://api.atlassian.com/",
    "https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Fable",
      "logoUrl": "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5fe143c5b48f8aab75293f8e/60230e8975a93a6b391baaeb_fable_ikon_16x16_transparent2.png",
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "layoutProperties": {
        "secondaryColor": "#00BFA6"
      },
      "universalActions": [
        {
          "label": "Learn more about Fable",
          "openLink": "https://tryfable.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    "docs": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe share more insight? Some code and [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added in some edits @Raserhin, thanks

Comment: This seems to be a problem not with your code but an actual bug on Google Workspace addons and triggers. I could confirm that after refreshing it does work. What about posting this as a [bug in Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gsuite-support#bugs). I think that they can solve your problem much better.

Comment: Thanks, I filed a bug last week and its open on issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180946036